# Oauth Authentication: 404 error when selecting "Add Application" under permitted apps

Tags: versionone

Trying to set up OAuth under VersionOne, recently upgraded to the Spring '13 Release. When I get to Administer a user, I select 'Permitted Apps', under 'Add Application', I choose 'Installed' for a desktop app, give it a Name, then click 'Add Application' -- I get a 404 error. Has anyone seen this behavior/have a fix?

Answer (score 0):

That page is designed to work from your member details popup, reachable from the top bar user menu, rather than the member administration area.  It's an oversight that it doesn't work in both places, and we have a defect filed for it.

In the future, the best place for questions like this (that don't involve our APIs or programming against VersionOne) is our product support area at https://support.versionone.com/home